# Function should be called until my array become empty

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, loops, for-loop

I'm having an array of data, i need to call a API Function and use my array value. Each time the API is hitting respected value should be deleted and my function should be called until the array becomes empty.

Comment: Your profile says, you are a budding artificial intelligence analyst. So what have you tried? Show us some code please.

Comment: show your tried code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example.
call this method **process** first time and pass your array like

```
process(array)
```

it will call itself until array contains element/s.

```
let array = [1,2,3]

func process(_ array: [Int]){
    if array.isEmpty{ return }

    let element = array.first!
    //process element
    print(element)
    let newArray = Array(array.dropFirst())
    process(newArray)
}
```